# Why is this preventing the app from launching?

Tags: console, console-application

```
2/5/11 4:01:34 PM
CNCRA3-launcher[1838]
*** NSThread: ignoring exception '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index (-1 (or possibly larger)) beyond bounds (0)' that raised during thread perform of target 0x6075f0 and selector 'buttonPressed_Play:'
```

This is what happens when I press the "play" button. What can I do to launch the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have ObjC background but apparently in `buttonPressed_Play` you call `objectAtIndex` with out-of-bounds index.